# How to make FileReader read from website files in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am learning how to use HTML and JavaScript to make a website, and I recently learned how to upload a file and take input from it by using HTML's input class.  Here is my code:

**TestFileIO.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Read Text File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="textToChange">Hello World!</h1>

    <input type="file" id="upload">

    <br>

    <p id="outputBx"></p>

    <script src="/JS_Scripts/testFileIOAgain.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**TestFileIO.js**

```
console.log('this is testFileIO.js');

let upload = document.getElementById('upload');

let outputBx = document.getElementById('outputBx');

upload.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
    //Initialize file reader

    let fr = new FileReader();

    fr.readAsText(upload.files[0]);

    fr.onload = function()
    {
        outputBx.innerHTML = fr.result;
    };


});
```

What I need to do next is read a file stored on the site, with filepath *"Website_Data/Recipes/Ultimate_Cookies.recp"*.  How do I change my code to read from that file, instead of one uploaded by the user?

I've tried using JavaScript's File class and telling the FileReader to read it:

**TestFileIO.js (changed)**

```
console.log('this is testFileIO.js');

let upload = document.getElementById('upload');

let outputBx = document.getElementById('outputBx');

upload.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
    //Initialize file reader

    let fr = new FileReader();

    fileToRead = new File([""], "Website_Data/Recipes/Ultimate_Cookies.recp", []);
    fr.readAsText(fileToRead);

    
    outputBx.innerHTML = fr.result;


});
```

But nothing happened.

Comment: if the file you want read is on the server then use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), `fetch('./path/to.recp').then(response => outputBx.innerHTML = response.text())`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone by "on the server" are you talking about stuff in my program files?  My program files have 5 folders containing HTML files, CSS files, JS files, images, and text files.  I am trying to read a file from the folder containing text files.

Comment: for any file to be accessible, it must be in the webroot (unless you add a file loader in the backend) i.e if its `/var/www/html/Website_Data/Recipes/Ultimate_Cookies.recp` it would work, but `C://Website_Data/Recipes/Ultimate_Cookies.recp` etc wont, unless s you add a file in the backend to load it and pass it to the client

Comment: @ZacharyLund - if you want to read a file without user interaction, you must use `fetch` (new method) or XMLHttpRequest (old method). Each of these require that you're running a webserver on your machine and that the files exist within the folders it can 'see' (in the webroot, or a child of it.) You cannot simply double-click an html file somewhere on disk to access it in a browser, since that file will be considered to have a different origin (null) than the file it's requesting (file:///). It will be blocked by the CORS policy.